# AmCharts replace dataset selector combobox for text field with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, dataset, selector, amcharts, stock

I'm using the javascript AmCharts Stock chart utility, and I want to replace the default combobox/dropdown DataSetSelector for comparing/selecting the data set for something more user-friendly, like a text field with autocomplete.

Is this possible and how can it be done?